# Почему не работает передача данных через сокет

Tags: java, android, сокет

Я хочу сделать чтобы одно устройство посылало данные другому устройству, которое будет читать данные и добавлять в массив. Но отправлять данные не получается, но если закрыть приложение через многозадачность, то данные на втором устройстве отображаются.

Код:
`

```
            clientSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.234", 4004);
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));
            String word = "reader"; 
            System.out.println("OK");
            out.write(word);
            out.flush();
            String serverWord = in.readLine();
            System.out.println(serverWord);
```

`

**Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать так чтобы данные передавались не после закрытия приложения?**

Comment: Покажите код, который вы используете.

Comment: @RomanKonoval добавил

Comment: Нужен код и сервера тоже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно к тексту, который передаётся методу write() добавить \n